# Qt keeps building shared build no matter what options I choose

Tags: c++, qt

I have compiled Qt statically for a stand-alone build and I have created a kit where I have set everything to the directory of the QT Static build.

No matter what I do tho, even when I set this kit, it keeps building with the other one where it makes an .exe dependant ont Qt dlls.

I have this in my .pro file:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static-libgcc
CONFIG += static
```

Is there anything else I have to do? I have also set the directories in PATH in my enviroment variables to match the static Qt build.

I even edited qmake.conf and added these in the beginning:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS +=  -static-libgcc -static -enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc
CONFIG += staticlib
CONFIG += static
DEFINES += QT_STATIC_BUILD
DEFINES += STATIC
```

STILL no change, keeps building shared build!

**EDIT**: Here is what `qt.conf` looks like right now:

```
[Paths]
Libraries=../lib/qtcreator
Plugins=plugins
Imports=imports
Qml2Imports=qml
```

**EDIT2**: I changed the `qt.conf` file:

```
[Paths]
Libraries=../lib/qtcreator
Plugins=plugins
Imports=imports
Qml2Imports=qml
Prefix=D:/Qt5.1.0/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.1/qtbase
```

However I think I need to set some other parameter too, because right now it's trying to `make` an already compiled object and is giving a strange error:

```
:-1: error: No rule to make target 'D:/Qt5.1.0/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.1/lib/qtcreator/libQt5Widgetsd.a', needed by 'debug\myQApp.exe'.  Stop.
```

Here is what the relevant part of the generated makefile is:

```
first: all
all: Makefile.Debug  $(DESTDIR_TARGET)

$(DESTDIR_TARGET): 
D:/Qt5.1.0/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.1/lib/qtcreator/libQt5Widgetsd.a 
D:/Qt5.1.0/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.1/lib/qtcreator/libQt5Networkd.a 
D:/Qt5.1.0/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.1/lib/qtcreator/libQt5Guid.a 
D:/Qt5.1.0/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.1/lib/qtcreator/libQt5Cored.a
```

**NOTE**: ignore the `Qt5.1.0` folder in the directory, I was writing it by hand, it's 5.1.1 in fact.

Comment: Did you perform a clean action and re-run qmake before building?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall yes I just cleaned and re-ran qmake and built again just to be sure, itkeeps making a small 29mb exe (afaik the debug static build should be huge) that expects to link to qt dlls.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall is there anything I should be looking for in the generated makefile when I run qmake? Something that might be wrong?

Comment: @shortage_radeon From the answer below the problem is more likely with #2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building Qt application linked with statically built Qt framework involves the following:

1. Statically built Qt framework. This topic involves configuring and running Qt own build from the source code. It is hard to cover in this answer. But there are many [links](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=qt%20statically%20built). I can probably answer more if I have concrete question about that. Mind the configuration you used for building Qt especially platform parameter that points to [i]make spec[/i]. The make spec you have set for the Qt configuration should be compatible with your application build/compiler/libraries e.g.:

   configure -static -debug-and-release [i]-platform win32-msvc2013[/i] -openssl -I %OPENSSL_HOME%\include -L %OPENSSL_HOME% -nomake examples -nomake tests -confirm-license -opengl es2 -skip qtwebkit -skip qtwebkit-examples -skip qttools

You need to make sure that make spec located in  qtbase\mkspecs is correct one and if needed modify one. I have modified qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013\qmake.conf to use -MT -MTd compiler options instead of -MD -MDd to avoid linking dynamic run-time with static build and the same is set for the app project.

2. Your local Qt configuration points to statically built Qt framework. See [qt.conf](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html) "prefix" parameter. Make sure that qt.conf file is in the same directory where qmake tool accessible from the launch path. Point to prebuilt Qt:

   [Paths]

   Prefix=C:/Qt/5.3/Src.64/qtbase #qtbase is where to point to
3. The Qt app someApp.pro file has proper definitions for the static app build and matching compiler settings. I can also probably answer more if I have concrete question about that.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, I have a qt.conf file in Tools\QtCreator\bin, I will try with this one and see if it works out. The "Prefix" parameter is missing, so it probably defaults to QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() as the documentation says. So I have to point it to the root of where the static libraries are compiled?

Comment: edit: I assume I also have to add something to the Libraries parameter? (I added qt.conf to the question description)

Comment: @shortage_radeon On one of my systems it points like that:

[Paths]
Prefix=C:/Qt/5.3/Src.64/qtbase
 #qtbase is the leaf

Comment: Not necessarily all the parameters used. I don't point to libraries like that but if I need I will.

Comment: Ok, I think this would work, just one last question - does qt.conf have to be copied into some other path other than its original one in Tools\QtCreator\bin?

Comment: We need to make sure that qmake program is at the path where qt.conf is.

Comment: Ok I think this is the solution, it definately changed now, however when I clean, run qmake again and build, it says `:-1: error: No rule to make target 'D:/Qt5.1.0/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.1/lib/qtcreator/libQt5Widgetsd.a', needed by 'debug\myQapp.exe'.  Stop.`
The only compiler I ever used on this project was MinGW 4.8 32 bit, so there is no compiler mismatch.
Why would it want to "make" an already compiled object? It just has to link it at the end.

Comment: Oh yeah I found the issue, it's looking for the library in `/lib/qtcreator` when in fact it needs to look in `/qtbase/lib`, however the Prefix in `qt.conf` already points to`qtbase`, why is it making the assumption it's a different directory?

Comment: I believe qtbase is for historical Qt reasons. But it may look one level up or so where your entire static Qt build is. Oh, I just realized one thing is worth mentioning in the whole answer.

Comment: It seems to me you need to check on configuration for your static build vs. your app project. I have added that in chapter 1.